# How to properly export/import Typescript modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

First time writing a Typescript package (NPM / private package), but plenty of experience with Typescript itself.

Say my package is called "my-api". It exports classes to make API calls as well as the models consumed/returned by those API calls.

---

### structure

```
models/
  User.ts
  index.ts
services/
  BaseService.ts
  UserService.ts
  index.ts
index.ts
```

**models/User.ts**

```
export type User = { ... }
```

**models/index.ts**

```
export { User } from "./User.ts";
```

**services/BaseService.ts**

```
export abstract class BaseService { ... }
```

**services/UserService.ts**

```
export class UserService extends BaseService { ... }
```

**services/index.ts**

```
export { UserService } from "./UserService.ts";
```

**index.ts**

```
export * from "./models";
export * from "./services";
```

---

### declaration

My declaration ends up looking like this (abbreviated):

```
declare module "models/User" {
    export type User = { ... };
}

declare module "services/BaseService" {
    export abstract class BaseService { ... }
}

declare module "services/UserService" {
    import { BaseService } from "services/BaseService";
    export class UserService extends BaseService { ... }
}
```

Note that there is no encompassing `my-api` module, etc., these declarations are at the root.

### expected usage

In my app which includes `my-api` via NPM, I want to use these classes and types:

**CreateUserForm.ts**

```
import { User, UserService } from "my-api";

 // OR

import { User } from "my-api/models";
import { UserService } from "my-api/services";

export class CreateUserForm { ... }
```

### but it doesn't work

When building my outer project, Typescript complains:

> File '/home/.../my-project/ui/node_modules/my-api/my-api.d.ts' is not a module.

I don't know how to convince Typescript to create the appropriate definition.

### appendix

Declarations are generated using this command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc --project ./tsconfig-definition.json --outFile ./dist/my-api.d.ts
```

**tsconfig-definition.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": false
  },
  "include": [ "./src" ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2016"],
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```